# How to use transactions in Typeorm with typeorm-transactional-cls-hooked

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I can't get everything to run within the same transaction.

I have the following code:

```
export class TestService {
  repository: any;
  constructor(
  @Inject(TENANT_CONNECTION) private connection)
  {
    this.repository = connection.getRepository(Test)
  }`

 @Transactional()
  async agregar(tableNew: Test): Promise<Number> {
    const tableSave = this.repository.create(tableNew)
    await this.repository.save(tableSave)
    if(tableSave.default){
      await this.repository.update(
            {default:true,id:Not(tableSave.id)},
            {default:false}
      )
    }
    return tableSave.id 
}
```

The following is executed in the database:

```
query: START TRANSACTION
query: SELECT `Test`.`id` AS `Test_id`,`Test`.`default` AS `Test_default` FROM `test` `Test` WHERE `Test`.`id` IN (?) -- PARAMETERS: [0]
query: START TRANSACTION
query: INSERT INTO `test`(`id`,`default`) VALUES (?,?) -- PARAMETERS: [0,1]
query: COMMIT
query: UPDATE `test` SET `default` = ? WHERE (`default` = ? AND `id` != ?) -- PARAMETERS: [0,true,41]
query: COMMIT
```

As you can see, 2 transactions are executed, I need it to be only one

Answer (score 0):

Did you [initialize](https://github.com/odavid/typeorm-transactional-cls-hooked#initialization) cls-hooked namespace properly?

Comment: Yes, this is how I do it in main.ts: 
```import { initializeTransactionalContext,  patchTypeORMRepositoryWithBaseRepository } from 'typeorm-transactional-cls-hooked';
async function bootstrap() {
  initializeTransactionalContext()
  patchTypeORMRepositoryWithBaseRepository() 
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.enableCors();
  app.useGlobalPipes(
    new ValidationPipe({
      whitelist: true
    })
  );
}```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to only start 1 transaction across multiple service, Make main service like this @Transactional(), and sub service's propagation option  @Transactional(propagation: Propagation.MANDATORY). MANDATORY option will support main transaction